# Magento 1.7: add active home button in menu

Tags: magento, menu

Im trying to add a home button in the navigation of my magento store. A lot has been written and I found this code that does the job.

```
     <li class="home <?php echo !$_anyActive ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></span></a></li>
```

The only drawback is that it stays active while clicking on other categories. So it isn't behaving like the rest of the menu.

Any help?

Many thanks in advance!

Update:
Solved with the answer given below.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick for you...

```
<li class="home <?php if (Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() === Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl()):?> active<?php endif;?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></span></a></li>
```

As you can see it checks to see if the url matches the home url. If so it then sets the class `active`.

Comment: Your very welcome, glad to help. You have an option to select this as best answer as well :) Cheers